# socket.error: [Errno 10060] while sending an email with Python

Tags: python

I am learning Python and wanted to try a small python script where I can send email with that script.

My Code:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)


server.login("youremailusername", "password")


msg = "Hello! Test Script For Sending an email" 

server.sendmail("you@gmail.com", "target@example.com", msg)
```

Error Message:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Can some one please help me what with problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the network you're on might be blocking that port (587) for outgoing connections, or Google might be blocking your IP address. If you're on a VPS, you can check the firewall settings for your system and see if you can open it.